# Python - Pandas DF - Create a DataFrame with unique values based on 2 or more Columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a table with 100 columns and 1M records and loaded into Panda DF.

Example of records:

```
C1 C2 C3 ...
A  1  2
A  1  2
B  2  2
B  2  2
C  3  2
```

I want to make unique records based on 2 columns (C1 and C2) - basically I know that if 2 of them are the same - the rest of the columns are the same.

Result would be:

```
C1 C2 C3 ...
A  1  2
B  2  2
C  3  2
```

How to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: `drop_duplicates` takes a subset flag

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['C1', 'C2'])`